# nohup is not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: windows, python-2.7, nohup

I am trying to run an python script using nohup
I have used the following command

```
nohup python filename.py &
```

it shows the following error

```
nohup is not recognized as internal or external command
```

can anyone tell me why?

Comment: are you running it on windows?

Comment: @code frenzy...yes I am using windows

Comment: you are getting `nohup is not recognized as internal or external command`  as there is no `nohup` command on Windows. Read more below.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows OS, use:

```
start /min python filename.py &
```

On Windows, killing a parent process does not dictate that a child process be terminated. Therefore there is no direct `nohup` equallent.

Comment: ...I have used nohup in windows earlier and it runs fine but now it throws this error

Comment: Hi. So where is the output redirected to after running `start /min python filename.py &`. Thank you!